# Can NAudio be used with UWP Background App

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi2, naudio

I am using NAudio to process audio thru a Raspberry Pi using UWP - at present it is a foreground App and works well but when I try to compile as a Background App get build errors like "All interfaces that are implemented by exported types must be Windows Runtime interfaces" - I'm not too expert on this stuff so want to see if trying to do something that wont work

Answer (score 0):

To build a **Background Service** you need create a Windows Runtime Component and make sure it adheres to the limitations of Windows Runtime, as these components must be portable to all languages that UWP supports (including JavaScript).

Hence, all public methods of your background service must have compatible types and signatures. Here is a [list of compatible types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br205768(v=vs.85).aspx) that may appear as return types / parameters. If you need to pass in a custom type, you could use serailization to `string` using JSON for example.

For other limitations [refer to this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic#declaring-types-in-windows-runtime-components) in the Docs.

If you adhere to this, your code should compile without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at the new [`AudioGraph` APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs) to make a UWP audio application running on the Raspberry PI. I've used this successfully although haven't tried it with a background service. I go into detail about `AudioGraph` in my [UWP Audio Fundamentals Pluralsight course](https://pluralsight.pxf.io/c/1192349/424552/7490?u=www%2Epluralsight%2Ecom%2Fcourses%2Fuwp-audio-fundamentals) although I'm afraid it does require a Pluralsight subscription to watch.